# What is the actual instance of a view in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am pretty new to iOS development and programming in general. I have been trying to wrap my head around some basic concepts, especially 
views in app. What is confusing is the fact that we refer to a view as an instance of some class (e.g UIViewController) but in ViewController.swift we do not mention it (instance) anywhere, we just describe the class. So when is the actual instance being initialized. Is it every time that the screen refreshes itself and what’s on the screen in the moment between two refresh cycles is the actual instance?

Comment: You should read the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) and the [View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503). Both

Comment: a ViewController is not a view, it s a container class that controls a View that it creates. (hence the name). That's what in view controller you don't say self.frame, you say self.view.frame

Comment: A really useful thing is when you are running your app, you can get the full view hierarchy in the xcode UI.